# Simple Frequency Sort - Codewars Challenge - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, frequency

For this [CodeWars challenge](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a8d2bf60025e9163c0000bc/train/javascript), the idea is to sort the array by frequency of elements - from most occurring to least occurring. So

`solve([2,3,5,3,7,9,5,3,7]) = [3,3,3,5,5,7,7,2,9]`

What I've done is turned the array into a string, created a frequency map, pushed the items from that map into a sorted array, and then pushed the numerical values from the sorted array into a final array.

```js
function solve(arr){
  let myString = JSON.stringify(arr).split('');
  let newArr = String(myString).replace(/[[,]/gi, '').replace(/]/, '').split('');
  let map = {};
  let sortedArr = [];
  let stringArray = [];
  let finalArray = [];
  //create frequency map
  newArr.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (!map[value]) {
      map[value] = 0;
    }
    map[value] += 1;
  })
  //sort array of elements by frequency
  for (let key in map) {
    sortedArr.push([key, map[key]])
  }
  sortedArr = sortedArr.sort((a, b) => b[1] - a[1]);
  for (let i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
    stringArray.push((sortedArr[i][0].repeat(sortedArr[i][1])).split(''));
  }
  //make frequency array values numerical
  for (let i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    let smallArray = stringArray[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < smallArray.length; j++) {
      finalArray.push(Number(smallArray[j]));
    }
  }
  return finalArray;
}
console.log(solve([1,2,3,0,5,0,1,6,8,8,6,9,1]));
```

My code is working for the basic tests, but is failing all random tests, and, as far as I know, CodeWars doesn't provide inputs for the failed random tests - so I don't have an idea of knowing why my code is failing.

Please feel free to re-factor as well.

Comment: I would not do it with strings. I'd make an object that counted each value, then sort with that object as a reference.

Comment: First thing that stands out is that your approach doesn't handle multi digit numbers correctly, for example an array like `[21, 22]` will become `[2,1,2,2]`.

Comment: Instead of all that stringify-ing and replace-ing, you can just map the array, eg: `let newArr = arr.map(e => e.toString())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could first use `reduce` method to create an object where the value is the frequency of that specific number and then use the `sort` method to first sort by frequency and if two numbers have the same frequency then you can sort by number.

```js
function solve(data) {
  const freq = data.reduce((r, e) => {
    if (!r[e]) r[e] = 1;
    else r[e]++;
    return r;
  }, {})

  return [...data].sort((a, b) => {
    return freq[b] - freq[a] || a - b
  })
}

console.log(solve([1, 2, 3, 0, 5, 0, 1, 6, 8, 8, 6, 9, 1]))
console.log(solve([2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 9, 5, 3, 7]))
```